# Display User That Is Does Not Exist in Other Table

Tags: sql, oracle, having

I have query that I am supposed to display  The number of patients a physician can take on. He can have no more than 5 patients at a time. I have this query working with the following:

```
select PHYSICIAN.PHYSICIAN_ID,PHYSICIAN.firstname_physician,PHYSICIAN.lastname_physician, phone.phone_number, 5-count(patient.patient_id) as "Numbers of new patients he/she can take"
from patient, physician, physician_phone, phone
where physician.physician_id = patient.physician_id and PHYSICIAN_PHONE.PHYSICIAN_ID = PHYSICIAN.PHYSICIAN_ID and phone.PHONE_ID = physician_phone.PHONE_ID
group by PHYSICIAN.PHYSICIAN_ID, PHYSICIAN.firstname_physician, PHYSICIAN.lastname_physician, physician_phone.phone_id, phone.phone_number
having count(patient.patient_id)<5;
```

However this only displays the physicians that have patients not the physicians who have 0 patients connected to them.

My attempt to display the physicians who also have 0 patients was the following:

```
    select PHYSICIAN.PHYSICIAN_ID,PHYSICIAN.firstname_physician,PHYSICIAN.lastname_physician, phone.phone_number, 5-count(patient.patient_id) as "Numbers of new patients he/she can take"
from patient, physician, physician_phone, phone
where physician.physician_id = patient.physician_id and PHYSICIAN_PHONE.PHYSICIAN_ID = PHYSICIAN.PHYSICIAN_ID and phone.PHONE_ID = physician_phone.PHONE_ID
group by PHYSICIAN.PHYSICIAN_ID, PHYSICIAN.firstname_physician, PHYSICIAN.lastname_physician, physician_phone.phone_id, phone.phone_number
having count(patient.physician_id)<5 OR NOT EXISTS ( Select patient.physician_id from patient  Where patient.physician_id != physician.physician_Id group by patient.physician_id)
```

Below are the table creates to help anyone better understand the relationship between the tables

```
    Create Table Physician (
    Physician_ID        integer     not null,
    Firstname_physician Char(30Char)     not null,
    lastname_physician  Char(30Char)     not null,

    Constraint Physician       Primary Key (Physician_ID));
Create Table Patient (
Patient_ID                  integer           not null,
Patient_FirstName           Char(20Char)        not null,
Patient_LastName            Char(20Char)        not null,
Patient_MI                  Char(1Char)         not null,
Patient_Gender              Char(15Char)        not null,
Staff_id                    integer             not null,
Physician_ID                integer             not null,

Constraint Patient_pk             Primary Key     (Patient_ID),
Constraint HomeCareStaff_fk       Foreign Key     (Staff_ID)    References HomeCareStaff(Staff_id),
Constraint Physician_ID_fk10      Foreign Key      (Physician_ID)   References Physician(Physician_ID));
```

Both tables queries return the same exact thing. Please see image [results of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9UCP.png)

Hope this makes sense Here are also the inserts

```
--populating Physician table--
insert into Physician values (100, 'Sasia', 'Applebottom');
insert into Physician values (101, 'Mac', 'Cheese');
insert into Physician values (102, 'Mick', 'Donalds');
insert into Physician values (103, 'Saint', 'West');
insert into Physician values (104, 'Chicago', 'West');
insert into Physician values (105, 'Mason', 'Disic');

---Populate Patient Table
insert into Patient values (150, 'Hayley', 'Beachump', 'F', 'Female', 50, 100);
insert into Patient values (151, 'Jacob', 'Stutzmen', 'K', 'Male', 51, 100);
insert into Patient values (152, 'Christina', 'Smush', 'P', 'Female', 52, 100);
insert into Patient values (153, 'Doris', 'Dorphish', 'D', 'Female', 53,100);
insert into Patient values (154, 'Adam', 'Wang', 'M', 'Male', 54, 100);
insert into Patient values (155, 'Levina', 'Reinhart', 'U', 'Female', 55, 101);
insert into Patient values (156, 'Harper', 'Mosbey', 'M', 'Male', 56, 102);
```

Comment: You need to left outer join your patient table to the physician table. It would be far easier to amend your query if you had already used the ANSI join syntax (eg. `...from physician py inner join physician_phone pp on py.physician_id = pp.physician_id left outer join patient pt on py.physician_id = pt.physician_id ...`).

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
select PHYSICIAN.PHYSICIAN_ID, PHYSICIAN.firstname_physician, PHYSICIAN.lastname_physician, phone.phone_number, count(patient.patient_id) as "Numbers of new patients he/she can take"
from patient, physician, physician_phone, phone
where physician.physician_id = patient.physician_id and PHYSICIAN_PHONE.PHYSICIAN_ID = PHYSICIAN.PHYSICIAN_ID and phone.PHONE_ID = physician_phone.PHONE_ID
group by PHYSICIAN.PHYSICIAN_ID, PHYSICIAN.firstname_physician, PHYSICIAN.lastname_physician, physician_phone.phone_id, phone.phone_number
having count(patient.patient_id) = 0;
```

Comment: i tried running this and it returned no results . if it helps these ill add the insert to the original post there isnt many

Comment: Might be from where. Here is 1 w/ out

Select Physician.Firstname_physician as "Physician First Name", lastname_physician as "Physician LastName", Phone.Phone_Number as "Physician Phone", Physician.Physician_ID as "Staff ID"
from Physician
Inner JOIN
    Physician_Phone on Physician.Physician_ID=Physician_phone.physician_id
Inner JOIN 
    Phone ON Physician_phone.phone_id=Phone.Phone_id
Left OUTER JOIN
    Patient ON Physician.Physician_ID=Patient.Physician_ID
where physician.physician_id IN (select physician_id from Patient group by physician_ID having count (physician_id) < 5  );